# Replace a string and keep the replaces string with coffeeScript

Tags: regex, coffeescript

I have the following script to delete a the digits at the end of an string and memorize the

```
initValues: (input)->
    value = $(input).val()

    split =  input.selectionStart

    @sub1 = value.substring(0, split).replace /\d*$/, (match) =>
        @firstDigit = match
        ''

    @firstDigit
```

Wonder if there is a way to keep `firstDigit` in the scope of the `initValue` function like this:

```
initValues: (input)->
    value = $(input).val()

    split =  input.selectionStart

    @sub1 = value.substring(0, split).replace /\d*$/, (match) ->
        firstDigit = match
        ''

    firstDigit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare it outside the callback function:

```
initValues: (input)->
    value      = $(input).val()
    split      = input.selectionStart
    firstDigit = null
    @sub1 = value.substring(0, split).replace /\d*$/, (match) ->
        firstDigit = match
        ''
    firstDigit
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/uRFNq/

You might want to use a different name than `firstDigit` though as `firstDigit` won't necessarily contain the first digits in the string, it will contain the *trailing* digits.